# How to use/persist POCO object relationships in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco, entity-framework-5

I have some POCO objects that look something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FooProperty { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BarProperty { get; set; }
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Each Foo object has exactly one Bar (and vice-versa).

Now I want to create a new pair of Foo/Bar objects. So I do this (and this is where I suspect I'm going wrong):

```
var foo = new Foo() { FooProperty = "hello" };

dbContext.Foos.Add(foo);

var bar = new Bar() { BarProperty = "world" };

foo.Bar = bar;

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

As you can probably tell, I'm hoping that because I "added" `foo`, then `bar` will also be added because it's part of the same object graph, but no: it isn't added - and nor is the `FooId` of the `Bar` object updated after the call to `SaveChanges` (though the `Id` of the Foo object *is* updated).

So, my guess is that this behaviour is because I'm dealing with POCOs and not EF proxy objects, and so there's no "plumbing" to make this work. I could fetch the `Id` from the `Foo` object and manually stash it in the `Bar` object (and vice-versa) and make some more calls to `SaveChanges`, but obviously that's not the right way to go.

So, presumably I need to create EF proxy objects rather than bare POCO objects. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: There's no "error", but the DB tables aren't updated as I wanted, and nor are the POCO objects updated.

Comment: Have you done configuration in the DbContext object to link the BarId and virtual Bar properties together?  I suspect your database contains additional fields such as `Foo_Id` as well as your `FooId` if you've not

Comment: Yes, I did a bit of HasRequired/WithRequired stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the entities meet the requirements for creating proxy objects, you can make this work by calling the create function from the context itself:

```
    var foo = dbContext.Foos.Create();
    dbContext.Foos.Add(foo);
    var bar = dbContext.Bars.Create();
    foo.Bar = bar;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured it must be something like that.